# Google Dataproc with Flink job capabilities

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

For requirements I need to use Dataproc for triggering a Flink job. I would like to do that in a reusable way using `workflow template`, but looking at the documentation seems not possible.

The only option seems to create a Dataproc cluster, then ssh into the master and run the Flink job from it.

I would like to know if this is the only option ( maybe I missed something in the documentation).

Another doubt regarding the approach above is that I need also to automate the triggering  of the job for example like Airflow  `Google composer` and I wondering how to achieve that because the operator if I saw well is missing, so another way could be trigger the execution running a bash command via `BashOperator`.

Could you suggest me some best practices in order to handle a scenario like that?

Thanks in advance.